# Вывод белого пустого места, вместо картинки

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

Начал изучать возможности питона 3.6 и столкнулся с такой проблемой. 
Если я хочу открыть фотку из программы, то она корректно открывается. Если из функции то вместо фотки отображается только белый прямоугольник. 
Может кто помочь?

```
from tkinter import *
import json
import string
from PIL import ImageTk, Image
import requests
import urllib.request, io
root=Tk()
root.title("Join")
root.geometry("1000x1000")
root.configure(background='grey')
text1=Text(root,height=7,width=7,font='Arial 14',wrap=WORD)
text1.pack()
button1=Button(root,text='ok',width=25,height=5,bg='black',fg='red', 
font='arial 14')
button1.pack()
def leftclick(event):
 l=text1.get('1.0',END)
 pay={'q':l}
 r=requests.get("https://api.vk.com/method/photos.search?v=5.64",params=pay)
 l = r.json()
 print (l["response"]["items"])
 URL=l["response"]["items"][0]["photo_130"]
 with urllib.request.urlopen(URL) as url:
      f = io.BytesIO(url.read())
 img1 = Image.open(f)
 img = ImageTk.PhotoImage(img1)
 panel = Label(root, image=img)
 panel.pack()
 button1.bind('<Button-1>', leftclick)
 root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Пробовали ту картинку сохранить в файл и посмотреть `open('img.jpg', mode='wb').write(url.read())`?

Comment: Только что попробовал, пустой файл. Как то странно в функции пустой файл, в самой тексте программы все ок. Что я не так делаю в функции?

Comment: Вот если разберетесь почему файл пустой, решите свою проблему

Answer (score 1):

**Вот так катит) panel.mainloop() добавьте в функцию**

```
from tkinter import *
import json
import string
from PIL import ImageTk, Image
import requests

from time import sleep
root = Tk()
root.title("Join")
root.geometry("500x500")
root.configure(background='grey')

def img_load(event):
    r = requests.get("https://api.vk.com/method/photos.search?v=5.64")
    l = r.json()
    #print (l["response"]["items"])
    URL=l["response"]["items"][0]["photo_130"]
    print(URL)
    r1 = requests.get(URL)
    f = open('image.jpg','wb')
    f.write(r1.content)
    f.close()

    img = Image.open('image.jpg')
    image = ImageTk.PhotoImage(img)
    panel = Label(image=image)
    panel.pack()
    panel.mainloop()
button = Button(root,text='ok',width=5,height=1,fg='red', font='arial 14') 
button.pack()
button.bind('<Button-1>', img_load)

root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1):

Добавлю и свою реализацию

```
import io
import random
import requests

from PIL import ImageTk, Image
from tkinter import *
    
    
root = Tk()
root.title("Join")
root.geometry("500x1000")
root.configure(background='grey')

text1 = Text(root, height=7, width=7, font='Arial 14', wrap=WORD)
text1.pack()

button1 = Button(root, text='Add new image', width=25, height=5, 
                 bg='black', fg='red', font='arial 14')
button1.pack()


def left_click(event):
    rs = requests.get("https://api.vk.com/method/photos.search?v=5.64")
    img_urls = rs.json()["response"]["items"]

    # Перемешивает список
    random.shuffle(img_urls)

    url = img_urls[0]["photo_130"]
    rs = requests.get(url)

    bytes_io = io.BytesIO(rs.content)
    img = Image.open(bytes_io)
    img = ImageTk.PhotoImage(img)

    panel = Label(root, image=img)
    panel.pack()
    panel.mainloop()


button1.bind('<Button-1>', left_click)
root.mainloop()
```

Результат:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]